# CSS: Text under image div in empty space

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to modify the default bootstrap blog template in order to add a small image next to the title.
I managed to add the image with `margin-left:auto;` but now the text won't go under it and only uses half of card:

[image: featured post]

```css
  .blog-header {
        line-height: 1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
      }
      
      .blog-header-logo {
        font-family: "Playfair Display", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-size: 2.25rem;
      }
      
      .blog-header-logo:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      
      h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        font-family: "Playfair Display", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
      }
      
      .display-4 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
      }
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .display-4 {
          font-size: 3rem;
        }
      }
      
      .nav-scroller {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        height: 2.75rem;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
      
      .nav-scroller .nav {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        margin-top: -1px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      }
      
      .nav-scroller .nav-link {
        padding-top: .75rem;
        padding-bottom: .75rem;
        font-size: .875rem;
      }
        
      .flex-auto {
        -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
      }
      
      .h-250 { height: 250px; }
      /* @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .h-md-250 { height: 250px; }
      } */
      
      .border-top { border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
      .border-bottom { border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
      
      .box-shadow { box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05); }
      
      /*
       * Blog name and description
       */
      .blog-title {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 2rem;
        font-weight: 400;
      }
      .blog-description {
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        color: #999;
      }

      
      /* Pagination */
      .blog-pagination {
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
      }
      .blog-pagination > .btn {
        border-radius: 2rem;
      }
       
      .imagine {
        max-width: 250px;
      }
    
      @media (min-width: 990px) {
        .imagine {
          max-width: 350px;
        }
      }
    
      @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .imagine {
          max-width: 120px;
          max-height: 90px;
          margin-top: 15px;
          margin-right: 15px;
          border-radius: 4px;
        }
      }
    
      @media (max-width: 320px) {
        .imagine {
          display: none;
        }
      }
    
      @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .card {
          flex-direction: row;
        }
      }
```

```html
    <!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <title>Bootstrap Blog</title>  
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:700,900" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/blog.css" rel="stylesheet">
      </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250">
            <div class="card-body">
              <!-- <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">World</strong> -->
              <h3>
                <a class="text-dark" href="#" width="50%;">Featured post</a>
              </h3>
                <div class="mb-1 text-muted">Nov 12</div>
              <div style="width:100%">
              <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            </div>
              <a href="#">Continue reading</a>
            </div>
            <img class="imagine" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <footer class="blog-footer">
        <p>
          <a href="#">Back to top</a>
        </p>
      </footer>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/assets/js/vendor/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I can't get the text to go full width and under the images. If I remove the image the text goes full width but with image it will wrap to image.
Image height is not 100%.

Comment: Put the image as the first child into `.card-body`, and then simply float it to the right …

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. If i do that, when resizing the image won't show up: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGREYY

Comment: Not what I meant, place the image directly after the opening tag `<div class="card-body">` - _inside_ that element, not after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put title and image in a div with card-title css added below css

```
.card-title{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.card-title img{
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```css
.card-title{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.card-title img{
  margin-left: auto;
}

.blog-header {
        line-height: 1;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
      }
      
      .blog-header-logo {
        font-family: "Playfair Display", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
        font-size: 2.25rem;
      }
      
      .blog-header-logo:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
      }
      
      h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
        font-family: "Playfair Display", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
      }
      
      .display-4 {
        font-size: 2.5rem;
      }
      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .display-4 {
          font-size: 3rem;
        }
      }
      
      .nav-scroller {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        height: 2.75rem;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
      
      .nav-scroller .nav {
        display: -webkit-box;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        margin-top: -1px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      }
      
      .nav-scroller .nav-link {
        padding-top: .75rem;
        padding-bottom: .75rem;
        font-size: .875rem;
      }
        
      .flex-auto {
        -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
        -webkit-box-flex: 0;
        flex: 0 0 auto;
      }
      
      .h-250 { height: 250px; }
      /* @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .h-md-250 { height: 250px; }
      } */
      
      .border-top { border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
      .border-bottom { border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
      
      .box-shadow { box-shadow: 0 .25rem .75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .05); }
      
      /*
       * Blog name and description
       */
      .blog-title {
        margin-bottom: 0;
        font-size: 2rem;
        font-weight: 400;
      }
      .blog-description {
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        color: #999;
      }

      
      /* Pagination */
      .blog-pagination {
        margin-bottom: 4rem;
      }
      .blog-pagination > .btn {
        border-radius: 2rem;
      }
       
      .imagine {
        max-width: 250px;
      }
    
      @media (min-width: 990px) {
        .imagine {
          max-width: 350px;
        }
      }
    
      @media (max-width: 767px) {
        .imagine {
          max-width: 120px;
          max-height: 90px;
          margin-top: 15px;
          margin-right: 15px;
          border-radius: 4px;
        }
      }
    
      @media (max-width: 320px) {
        .imagine {
          display: none;
        }
      }
    
      @media (max-width: 767px) {

      }
```

```html
<div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250">
            <div class="card-title">
              <h3>
                <a class="text-dark" href="#" width="50%;">Featured post</a>
              </h3>
              <img class="imagine" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <!-- <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">World</strong> -->
              
                <div class="mb-1 text-muted">Nov 12</div>
              <div style="width:100%">
              <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            </div>
              <a href="#">Continue reading</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting the image in a div with title and date only

like this

```
<div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250">
            <div class="card-body">
              <!-- <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">World</strong> -->
              <div><h3>
                <a class="text-dark" href="#" width="50%;">Featured post</a>
              </h3>
                <div class="mb-1 text-muted">Nov 12</div>
               <img class="imagine" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg"></div>
              <div style="width:100%">
              <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            </div>
              <a href="#">Continue reading</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> next to the title

Your image is just in the wrong place. If you want it next to the title, it should be in the same div as the title div. In your code that is the div with class *card-body*.

To make it float right, you need to add float: right; to your css. The image should be the first child of the div with class *card-body*.

```css
.blog-header {
    line-height: 1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  }

  .blog-header-logo {
    font-family: "Playfair Display", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
    font-size: 2.25rem;
  }

  .blog-header-logo:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-family: "Playfair Display", Georgia, "Times New Roman", serif;
  }

  .display-4 {
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }

  @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .display-4 {
      font-size: 3rem;
    }
  }

  .nav-scroller {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    height: 2.75rem;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }

  .nav-scroller .nav {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    padding-bottom: 1rem;
    margin-top: -1px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  }

  .nav-scroller .nav-link {
    padding-top: 0.75rem;
    padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
    font-size: 0.875rem;
  }

  .flex-auto {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }

  .h-250 { height: 250px; }

  /* @media (min-width: 768px) {
    .h-md-250 { height: 250px; }
  } */

  .border-top { border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }
  .border-bottom { border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5; }

  .box-shadow { box-shadow: 0 0.25rem 0.75rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05); }

  /*
   * Blog name and description
   */
  .blog-title {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  .blog-description {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    color: #999;
  }


  /* Pagination */
  .blog-pagination {
    margin-bottom: 4rem;
  }

  .blog-pagination > .btn {
    border-radius: 2rem;
  }

  .imagine {
    max-width: 250px;
  }

  @media (min-width: 990px) {
    .imagine {
      max-width: 350px;
      float: right;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .imagine {
      float: right;
      max-width: 120px;
      max-height: 90px;
      margin-top: 15px;
      margin-right: 15px;
      border-radius: 4px;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 320px) {
    .imagine {
      display: none;
    }
  }

  @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .card {
      flex-direction: row;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="row mb-2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="card flex-md-row mb-4 box-shadow h-md-250">
        <div class="card-body">
        <img class="imagine" src="https://www.w3schools.com/css/paris.jpg">
          <!-- <strong class="d-inline-block mb-2 text-primary">World</strong> -->
          <h3>
            <a class="text-dark" href="#" width="50%;">Featured post</a>
          </h3>
            <div class="mb-1 text-muted">Nov 12</div>
          <div style="width:100%">
          <p class="card-text mb-auto">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
        </div>
          <a href="#">Continue reading</a>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```